# nativescript android resource not found

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm trying to run a really simple nativescript project on android emulator. 
I generated the project using NativeScript CLI (It's an angular project).

when I do the 'tns run android' 
I have this error :

```
An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xfffffff6
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:216)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2155)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getAnimation(Resources.java:1180)
    at android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(AnimationUtils.java:137)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.loadAnimation(FragmentManager.java:1073)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1554)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:710)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

I don't know what i did wrong. 
 any of you have any tips on how to debug it?

Sincerly 
Adrien

Comment: Which version of NativeScript you are using? Are you using any plugins?

Comment: I'm using 4.2.4 and i haven't installed any particular plugins ( except the angular-cli) . I'm gonna try to remove everything and install everything again (tomorrow).

Comment: Please make sure you are using 4.x android run time.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the vue.js project and solved it by selecting TabView when generating the project. And make sure u installed lates version 5.0.0
npm i -g nativescript@latest, before u created project.